# IE 10 Websocket Error which bypass proxy server in Meteor project

Tags: proxy, websocket, meteor

I use IE 10 to run Meteor project with IP Address but it error in console log

"SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 403, Forbidden"

I test uncheck "Use a proxy server" in Internet Option it work, but my office must use proxy server.

How i cant fix this problem ?

Thank you every much

Answer (score 0):

Your web proxy must support websockets to use them. Meteor will automatically fall back to long polling over http for cases like this. You can still use everything as normal but it'll take a bit longer to load (its very slight).

This error comes about because meteor is trying to use websockets and if it fails it falls back to long polling.

If you know you always want to use XHR/Longpolling without trying websockets start meteor with `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS` as an environment variable